# To check whether image file exist or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
string serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/web" + event.Image_Url);
var isFileExist = File.Exists(serverPath);
```

The value of `event.Image_Url = /Resources/images/event-images/e1ae04a2-e63f-4831-a5ee-2f0d2713f8a2.png`

But it always gives `false` even though the file exist on the physical path.The physical path which it comes from above operation as shown below.

serverPath value = `D:\Freelance Work\Trunck\Api\web\Resources\images\event-images\e1ae04a2-e63f-4831-a5ee-2f0d2713f8a2.png`

But actually I need to go to the `web` folder.But it automatically gets the `Api` folder as shown above.How to avoid it ? Why it takes the `Api` folder ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note :** I have noticed that the `web api` project is also running on local host.May be that is the reason for it.But how can I tell it to get the virtual path from the `web` project ?

Folder structure **within Trunck** as follows.All are in same level.

```
Trunck --> API

       --> Web

       --> BLL
```

Comment: Where is your code being executed? In web controller.cs or a view or an API controller or somewhere else?

Comment: @ScottRickman `Trunck\Bll\Classes.cs`.This is a separate class project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the `/` at the start of the `event.Image_Url` field. That caused the last path in the string to be taken as a absolute path.

```
string serverPath = Path.Combine
                    ( HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
                    , @"..\web\"
                    , @event.Image_Url.TrimStart('/').Replace('/', '\\')
                    );
```

Comment: Do you need the Replace?  Doesn't path.combine do that for you?

Comment: @Hogan: `Path.Combine` doesn't replace them for you. Most .NET code is compatible with them though. Not *all* other programs, so I kept it in. (we had some major issues with one of the VS products, maybe MSBuild, because of this)

Comment: Looking at the codez -- http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,65c63f5b94b2ac9b  it seems you have to use one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try `string path= Server.MapPath("~/web"), serverPath =Path.Combine(path,event.Image_Url)` instead of <strike>string serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/web" + event.Image_Url);</strike>

Comment: My problem is `MapPath` gets the `webApi` project's path instead of the `web` project's path ?